# Как растянуть background-color в ширину

Tags: html, css

Как растянуть background-color на всю страницу в ширину? Чтобы это не выглядело так:(скриншот снизу)

Мой код:

```css
z {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<z style="margin-left: 1000px; color: yellow;">
  Текст
</z>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `background-color` нельзя растянуть, но можно добавить новый div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Текст
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Свойство "background-color" нельзя растянуть само по себе не растянув сам элемент при этом)
В Вашем случае, добавьте свойство "width: 100%;" к тэгу z (что это?).

И от свойства "margin-left: 1000px;" лучше отказаться: использование таких больших отступов не лучшая практика, не говоря уже о том, что при отступе серого фона не будет...

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш способ тоже рабочий, но ответ выше больше подошёл